# sox FAIL util: Unable to load MAD decoder library (libmad) function "mad_stream_buffer"

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, mp3, sox

I compiled libmad for sox.  When I try to read an mp3 I get this message:

sox FAIL util: Unable to load MAD decoder library (libmad) function "mad_stream_buffer".

Did I compile the project incorrectly?

Answer (score 73):

Steps to using SOX to create MP3s:

1. Download latest version of [SOX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/) and install.
2. Download `libmad-0.dll` and `libmp3lame-0.dll`. The currently only known trustworthy source is [ossbuild](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ossbuild/source/default/source) but this requires you to download a 1.5 GB archive. The selected two files are available [here](https://app.box.com/s/tzn5ohyh90viedu3u90w2l2pmp2bl41t) and [here](https://pastebin.com/PRy2P6SN).
3. Add `libmad-0.dll` and `libmp3lame-0.dll` to the folder where SOX was installed to.
4. Use the command line to convert a file to `.mp3`:

   ```
   sox input.wav -c 2 -C 128 output.mp3
   ```

*Note:  `-c 2` makes it stereo, `-C 128` specifies output as 128 kbps MP3*

Comment: I spent an hour fussing with trying to install LAME manually before I happened across this. Thank you and OSSBuild!

Comment: @bulltorious, I can not download `libmad-0.dll` and `lbmp3lame-0.dll`. If I press `Download` button in Box, I get error in Firebug: `"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - https://app.box.com/index.php?rm=box_download_shared_file&shared_name=tzn5ohyh90viedu3u90w2l2pmp2bl41t&file_id=f_69256952453"`. Thanks.

Comment: As of August 2017 .DLLs are still there in 1.5 GB archive. Thanks.

Comment: the link for just the two files is dead.

Comment: Download mirror: [libmad-0.dll](https://archive.org/details/libmad-0.dll) and [libmp3lame-0.dll](https://archive.org/details/libmp3lame-0.dll).

Comment: Working like a charm

Comment: Confirmed working on windows 10 pro, 64bit (the two "single file" links still work for me, I used the 7 zip version)

Answer (score 7):

You can download SoX binaries together with libmad.dll and libmp3lame.dll from http://www.videohelp.com/software/SoX

http://www.videohelp.com/download/sox-14.4.0-libmad-libmp3lame.zip

Answer (score 5):

Compiling SOX with Lame and Libmad for Windows
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Compiling_SOX_with_Lame.aspx

Comment: Useful article because the "finished" version (sox compiled with lame and libmad) is included.

Answer (score 4):

I have put together the original SoX binary and libmad and libmp3lame from http://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/source/browse/trunk/Shared/Build/Windows/Win32/bin/

[SoX binary for Win32 together with libmad and libmp3lame](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxRalAlWlsgjclFzOTVKLTBGUnM)

Answer (score 4):

I have put together the original SoX binary and libmad and libmp3lame from http://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/source/browse/trunk/Shared/Build/Windows/Win32/bin/

SoX binary for Win32 together with libmad and libmp3lame

Thanks that was easy.   Thanks for sharing this easy solution.

Comment: Here is the updated URL http://ossbuild.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Shared/Build/Windows/Win32/bin/

Answer (score 0):

for compiling from source:

since the the tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Compiling_SOX_with_Lame.aspx is rather dated (and did not work for me with more recent VisualStudio versions):
the SOX project contains ready-to-use Visual Studio projects for compiling SOX and its dependencies/libraries on Windows (e.g. using a Visual Studio Community Edition).

The SOX source code [repository at SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/code/) contains a directory `msvc10` (and also `msvc9`) for compiling SOX and its dependencies with VisualStudio.
Detailed instructions for that are in the [Readme.txt](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/code/ci/master/tree/msvc10/Readme.txt).

So, for example, for only compiling `libmad.dll`:

- clone SOX repository, e.g. to directory `sox-code/`

```
git clone https://git.code.sf.net/p/sox/code sox-code
```

- [download `libmad` source code from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mad/files/libmad/0.15.1b/) and decompress to directory `libmad/` (cf. instructions of the SOX VisualStudio Readme.txt, see link above), i.e. the directory structure should look like

```
sox-code/
libmad/
```

- open the VisualStudio project file (`*.sln`) in directory `sox-code/msvc10` *(if needed, change build configuration form `Debug` to `Release`)*
- in the Solution Explorer window open context-menu for sub-project `LibMad` and select `Build` (or in older VS versions `Project Only` → `Build Only LibMad`)
- afterwards the compiled DLL is in `sox-code/msvc10/Release` (or `Debug` depending on the selected configuration)

*tested with VisualStudio 2010 and Visual Studio 2017 CE*

Comment: excuse me, can you check this question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/65915925/12690890)? It is about libmad