# Python convert mp3 to wav with Pydub

Tags: python, audio, pydub

Ok, now I am stuck up in converting mp3 to wav. I have seen different answers but i think i would to go for the one of pydub, which i already did using these few lines

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

AudioSegment.from_mp3("/input/file.mp3").export("/output/file.wav", format="wav")
```

but when I run the above code, i get the following error

> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydub-0.14.2-py2.7.egg\pydub\utils.py:165: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/phourlhar/Desktop/VoiceDetector/yeah.py", line 7, in 
>       stereo_to_mono()
>
> File "C:\Users\phourlhar\Desktop\VoiceDetector\utils.py", line 25, in
>   stereo_to_mono
>
> ```
> sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(PROJECT_DIR+'\\files\\rec'+str(c)+'.mp3')
> ```
>
> File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 346, in
>   from_file
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>
> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I don't know why it raises this error as i am very sure the file exists. Although i have answers suggesting the installation of ffmpeg, but i dont know if affect the app deployment in any way later on

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `pydub` module uses either `ffmpeg` or `avconf` programs to do the actual conversion. So you do have to install `ffmpeg` to make this work.

But if you don't need `pydub` for anything else, you can just use the built-in `subprocess` module to call a convertor program like `ffmpeg` like this:

```
  import subprocess

  subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', '/input/file.mp3',
                   '/output/file.wav'])
```

This requires that the ffmpeg binary is in a location in your $PATH, by the way.

**Edit**: With `ffmeg`, you cannot convert stereo to mono, as far as I know. You can only *choose* the left or right channel. I'm assuming this is not what you want.

The [`sox`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) program *can* convert stereo to mono:

```
  import subprocess

  subprocess.call(['sox', '/input/file.mp3', '-e', 'mu-law', 
                   '-r', '16k', '/output/file.wav', 'remix', '1,2'])
```

This will sample at 16 kHz, with 8 bits/sample, giving you 16 kb/s.

Comment: thanks, it really helped. but now i need to convert mp3 file directly to mono wav with subprocess and ffmpeg, would really appreciate if u could give a hand

Comment: @user3760740 As far as I know, you cannot convert stereo input to mono output with `ffmpeg`. You can do this with `sox`, see updated answer.

Comment: @RolandSmtih thanks, would check out on the 'sox'. but is there a way i could force the output to be 16kb/s mono wav with sox

Comment: @user3760740 There are different combinations of encodings (sox `-e` option) and sample rate (sox `-r` option) that can accomplish that. Please see the [manual](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html). Which one is appropriate for your application is more than I can say. You will probably have to try which works best for you.

Comment: @user3760740 I've updated my answer to give one obvious option for 16 kb/s.

Comment: @RolandSmtih thanks, when i tried the above code, i get two sox errors     **sox FAIL util: Unable to load MAD decoder library (libmad).
sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `C:\Users\phourlhar\Desktop\VoiceDetector\files\test2.mp3':**

Comment: @user3760740 It seems the ms-windows version of `sox` doesn't come with mp3 support. Maybe the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537155/sox-fail-util-unable-to-load-mad-decoder-library-libmad-function-mad-stream) can help you further. I don't use ms-windows, so am unable to offer assistance in that regard.

Comment: Was getting errors using pydub to do conversion (which is using ffmpeg I believe). Used the subprocess call directly to ffmpeg and it fixed everything. Thanks!

Comment: but it returns no such file ofrdirectory ffmpeg

Answer (score 14):

You must go for pydub, it is a great module for operations related with audio files.

NOTE. Do remember to install ffmpeg before you use pydub.

For help regarding installation of **ffmpeg**, you can use this [link](http://adaptivesamples.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/).

Then to install pydub just open your command prompt and type

```
pip install pydub
```

Then to convert any file from mp3 to wav just use **pydub** as

```
import pydub
sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3("D:/example/apple.mp3")
sound.export("D:/example/apple.wav", format="wav")
```

Comment: Can we do the same operation and hold the audio stream object in memory instead of writing to a file?

Comment: Sort of. memfile = io.BytesIO(); sound.export(memfile, 'wav'); sound=AudioSegment.from_wav(memfile)

Comment: @user2647513 I get EOFError when trying to open that memfile

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the missing of `ffmpeg`. Pydub requires it to perform the operations of format conversion. To solve the problem, there are 2 ways:

1. Simply install pydub with ***conda, not pip*** (despite the suggestion on [Pydub's GitHub page](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub))

   ```
   conda install -c conda-forge pydub
   ```

This should work fine. Reason unknown, possibly due to the compatibility stuff.

2. The other solution (if you already used pip to install Pydub, and it does not work) is to install the missing `ffmpeg` package. Here comes another problem. Though we can find a package named `ffmpeg` on both [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg/) and [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ffmpeg), if we only installed one of the source, we will probably see the error like

   ```
   In [1]: import ffmpeg                                                                               
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-1-16f5f3b4de71> in <module>
   ----> 1 import ffmpeg

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffmpeg'
   ```

After several tests, I found that both have to be installed to make the package `ffmpeg` work (install twice, in other words). Otherwise, somehow python cannot find the package even if it has been installed via either pip or anaconda. So just type

```
pip install ffmpeg
conda install ffmpeg
```

Now try to import `ffmpeg` in python. If there is no error, the problem should already be solved.

**NOTE that**, manually downloading `ffmpeg` from [FFmpeg website](https://ffmpeg.org/) and append the `bin` path to `sys.path` might not help with this problem. Similarly, manually specifying the path to the executable of `ffmpeg` (on Windows it is `ffmpeg.exe`) might not solve the problem either.

Comment: Downloading the FFmpeg manually and set it to the environment variable path is working in Windows 10. Cmd or PowerShell session needs to be renewed after adding a new path. If it's not working try to add pydub path in environment variable path. You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480893/pydub-installation-and-ffmpeg?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Adding it to the path in Windows didn't work for me, but this did!  Thanks!