# Stop the audio from playing in pydub

Tags: python, audio, playback, pydub

Is there something like terminate or stop feature in pydub such that the stream after started by play() can be stopped abruptly while it is still playing instead of the audio being played to it's full length and then stopping.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned pydub itself provides no such feature.
However, it's possible to stop the music by using multiprocessing:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
from multiprocessing import Process

some_audio = AudioSegment.from_file('yourAudioFile.mp3')
process = Process(target=play, args=(some_audio,))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process.start()
    time.sleep(2000) # do some stuff inbetween
    process.terminate()
```

The method `terminate()`stops the process and with it the audio from playing.

**EDIT**

I found a *much* nicer way, sparing us unnecessarily heavy processes.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import _play_with_simpleaudio

some_audio = AudioSegment.from_file('yourAudioFile.mp3')
playback = _play_with_simpleaudio(some_audio)
time.sleep(2000)  # do some stuff inbetween
playback.stop()
```

More details: https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/160#issuecomment-497953546

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen, and I am using the whole sound processing for the first time, you could use pyaudio to play a wav-file as a stream. pyaudio is not pydub. :)

First, convert your anydata-file to a wav-file with pydub/ffmpeg, see below, and then use pyaudio to play it as a stream with logic between.

Because, when I play an MP3 with pydub, it waits some seconds and then states that the file has been converted to wav in a /tmp-folder. So, why not convert it just once and save it to your own location? It lasts some seconds both ways, anyway, but the latter converting has just to be done once (assuming you have tons of Gigabytes :) ), and then you can just check if the file already exists.

-> converting
[Python convert mp3 to wav with Pydub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073278/python-convert-mp3-to-wav-with-pydub#32073824)

-> playing and recording sound with python -> pyaudio (comprehensive guide)
https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/#pyaudio

As you see in the code, you could put your own logic into the while loop where the stream is played.

I will try to use that combination in a project I make. Hope it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to stop an playing audio in `pydub`  at this time since it can either use `pyaudio` or `ffplay` in the backend (depending on what's installed and accessible).
See details on backend code [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/playback.py)

However, you can hit *Ctrl + c* to break the play and wrap around `play` method in `try - except` block. It will generate  `KeyboardInterrupt` exception that you can process it according your needs.

Here is a working sample that's tested on `windows`.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

song = AudioSegment.from_wav("audio.wav")
while True:
    try:
        play(song)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Stopping playing"
        break #to exit out of loop, back to main program
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. i have tried a number of variations of the following code, including the above: `def ring():
    sound_alarm = True
    while True:
        try:
            print(f'sound_alarm is {sound_alarm}')
            if sound_alarm == False:
                return
            play(sound)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sound_alarm = False
            print('done playing sound.')
            break
`
I get the following: `sound_alarm is True
^Csound_alarm is True
^Csound_alarm is True
sound_alarm is True`
and it continues to loop endlessly

Comment: Do u have ^C setup on your linux terminal. For e.g. see if it works in standalone without script. Else you can setup with `stty intr ^c` and then try above.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by "do you have ^C setup...". I do use such key command on the command line frequently, so, I presume the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

At risk of being down voted for not referring to pydub, I thought I would share what I know at this point. I never got it to work with pydub and as far as I can tell, I used @Anil_M's answer. Let me share that again here as code formatting apparently does not work in comments.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

# music files
f = '/home/worldwidewilly/workspace/deliberate-action/action/on-the-run-snippet.mp3'

# run pydub
sound = AudioSegment.from_file(f, format="mp3")
def ring():
    sound_alarm = True
    while True:
        try:
            print(f'sound_alarm is {sound_alarm}')
            if sound_alarm == False:
                return
            play(sound)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sound_alarm = False
            print('done playing sound.')
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    ring()
```

When the above is executed and i press *ctrl+C*, the sound does stop playing, but it never gets to the KeyboardInterrupt logic, i.e. the `print('done playing sound.')` is never executed. It just goes to the top of the loop, inrt the statement, and plays the sound (so, obviously, var sound_alarm never equals False).

The solution I have come upon is to use simpleaudio. The downside is that I have yet to figure out how to play anything other than a *.wav* file. Here is the code for that:

```
# run simpleaudio
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(f)
def ring():
    # sound_alarm = True
    while True:
        try:
            play_obj = wave_obj.play()
            play_obj.wait_done()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            play_obj.stop()
            print('done playing sound.')
            break
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    ring()
```

Pressing *ctrl-C* here does stop the sound and it does end the loop. It is unclear why this logic would work for one and not the other, but there you have it. I would love to be enlightened.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Multithreading in the playback file of pydub to play/pause and even stop the music .

check the file here and replace the playback.py from pydub with this

https://github.com/NeelRanka/pydub_edited_play-pause-stop.git

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. If possible, include a small example for clarity. Thanks :)

Comment: https://github.com/NeelRanka/pydub_edited_play-pause-stop.git : check this